# Setting the ExtendedMetadata 'signingAlgorithm' field

Tags: spring-security, spring-saml

I'm having an issue getting the Spring SAML integration to generate the correct metadata file for my IdP.  I was issued new SHA256 SSL certs.  I've gone through all of the steps to create the appropriate keyStore and have my Spring security configuration file all set.  I am literally like 98% of the way there but there is one thing missing in the generated metadata file that I can't for the life of me figure out why it's not getting set.

Here is my ExtendedMetadata config for MetadataGeneratorFilter:

```
<bean id="metadataGeneratorFilter" class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataGeneratorFilter">
<constructor-arg>
    <bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataGenerator">
        <property name="entityId" value="urn:myentityidhere"/>
        <property name="entityBaseURL" value="https://${saml.url}"/>
        <property name="extendedMetadata">
            <bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.ExtendedMetadata">
                <property name="signMetadata" value="true"/>
                <property name="signingAlgorithm" value="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256"/>
                <property name="alias" value="ceo"/>
                <property name="signingKey" value="${saml.sp.alias}"/>
                <property name="encryptionKey" value="${saml.sp.alias}"/>
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>
</constructor-arg>
```

When I run my app and go to the /saml/metadata URI to get Spring to generate the metadata file I need to send to my IdP, the SHA256 algo gets correctly set on the SignatureMethod, but the child DigestMethod tag's algorithm value is still set to SHA1, when I need that ALSO set to SHA256 along with the DigestValue to be a SHA256 value and not a SHA1 value.

```
<ds:SignedInfo>
    <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
    <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256"/>
    <ds:Reference URI="#urn_myentityidhere">
        <ds:Transforms>
            <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"/>
            <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
        </ds:Transforms>
        <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
        <ds:DigestValue>xxxxxxx</ds:DigestValue>
    </ds:Reference>
</ds:SignedInfo>
```

Can someone guide me in how/what I need to set to get the DigestMethod algorithm value set to 256 also?  I figured since it is a child of the SignedInfo tag, it would inherit the signingAlgorithm value from the Extendedmetadata config, but alas it is not.

Any help would be GREATLY appreciated.  Thanks so much.

***SOLUTION - In case anyone cares***

So, after a day's worth of digging, I decided to just implement this myself.  I extended the ExtendedMetadata class by adding the field, digestMethodAlgorithm and added the appropriate getter/setters:

```
/**
 * Algorithm used for creation of digest method of this entity. At the moment only used for metadata signatures.
 * Only valid for local entities.
 */
private String digestMethodAlgorithm;

/**
 * Returns digest method algorithm value
 * @return String
 */
public String getDigestMethodAlgorithm()
{
    return digestMethodAlgorithm;
}

/**
 * Sets the digest method algorithm to use when signing the SAML messages.
 * This can be used, for example, when a strong algorithm is required (e.g. SHA 256 instead of SHA 128).
 * If this property is null, then the {@link org.opensaml.xml.Configuration} default algorithm will be used instead.
 *
 * Value only applies to local entities.
 *
 * At the moment the value is only used for signatures on metadata.
 *
 * Typical values are:
 * http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha1
 * http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256
 * http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha384
 * http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha512
 * http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#ripemd160
 *
 * @param digestMethodAlgorithm The new digest method algorithm to use
 * @see org.opensaml.xml.signature.SignatureConstants
 */
public void setDigestMethodAlgorithm(String digestMethodAlgorithm)
{
    this.digestMethodAlgorithm = digestMethodAlgorithm;
}
```

Then I modified my spring security configuration from above to include this new bean property to be set in my MetadataGenerator config:

```
<bean id="metadataGeneratorFilter" class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataGeneratorFilter">
<constructor-arg>
    <bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataGenerator">
        <property name="entityId" value="urn:myentityidhere"/>
        <property name="entityBaseURL" value="https://${saml.url}"/>
        <property name="extendedMetadata">
            <bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.ExtendedMetadata">
                <property name="signMetadata" value="true"/>
                <property name="signingAlgorithm" value="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256"/>
                <property name="digestMethodAlgorithm" value="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/>
                <property name="alias" value="ceo"/>
                <property name="signingKey" value="${saml.sp.alias}"/>
                <property name="encryptionKey" value="${saml.sp.alias}"/>
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>
</constructor-arg>
```

Then I also had to make two changes to the SAMLUtil class.  In getmetadataAsString, in the isSignMetadata() if-clause, I pulled out the injected value for the digestMethodAlgorithm set by the config above and then further modified the marshallAndSignMessage method to accept a new input parameter which I further use to get the DigestMethod algo set properly.

Inside of SAMLUtil.getMetaDataAsString, line 572

```
...
String digestMethodAlgorithm = extendedMetadata.getDigestMethodAlgorithm();
element = SAMLUtil.marshallAndSignMessage(descriptor, credential, signingAlgorithm, digestMethodAlgorithm, keyGenerator);
...
```

Inside of SAMLUtil.marshallAndSignMessage, right after line 437, I add/changed the following:

```
...
BasicSecurityConfiguration secConfig = null;

if (digestMethodAlgorithm != null)
{
    secConfig = (BasicSecurityConfiguration) Configuration.getGlobalSecurityConfiguration();

    secConfig.setSignatureReferenceDigestMethod(digestMethodAlgorithm);
}

try {
    SecurityHelper.prepareSignatureParams(signature, signingCredential, secConfig, keyInfoGenerator);
} catch (org.opensaml.xml.security.SecurityException e) {
    throw new MessageEncodingException("Error preparing signature for signing", e);
}
...
```

I recompiled the entire Spring SAML core package via Gradle, spring-security-saml-1.0.0.RELEASE, copied the new jar from the build/libs directory to my project, deployed the webapp, pointed my browser to /saml/metadata and successfully got the metadata file with the correct SHA256 signed portion of the metadata file.

I'm going to see what I can do about getting this committed to the git repo for this project because I don't want to lose this ability as the project does future releases.  Never contributed to an open-source project like this before.

```
<ds:SignedInfo>
<ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
<ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256"/>
<ds:Reference URI="#urn_myentityidhere">
    <ds:Transforms>
        <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"/>
        <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
    </ds:Transforms>
    <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/>
    <ds:DigestValue>xxxxxx</ds:DigestValue>
</ds:Reference>
```

Answer (score 14):

Things seem to have changed since the @VladimírSchäfer answer; it did not work for us with AD FS 2.0 and SHA-256. We had to add an extra setting to get it to work (see code, below).

The problem appears to be in OpenSAML's xmltooling library, specifically the `org.opensaml.xml.security.BasicSecurityConfiguration.getSignatureAlgorithmURI(Credential)` method - instead of just using the signature algorithm of the certificate (in our case, `SHA256withRSA`), it gets the *key* of the certificate, then looks at the algorithm of that key and uses a map of registered URIs to look up a signature URI. If they'd just have a map of JCA *signature algorithms* to URIs, instead of key algorithms to URIs, it would all be fine.

The workaround is to register the correct signature algorithm URI with `BasicSecurityConfiguration` during Spring wiring, overwriting the (undesirable) URI `http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1` that's already present with `http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256`.

We also had to *remove* the `setSignatureReferenceDigestMethod()` call, or importing metadata into AD FS would fail.

```
import org.opensaml.Configuration;
import org.opensaml.xml.security.BasicSecurityConfiguration;

import org.springframework.beans.BeansException;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.config.ConfigurableListableBeanFactory;
import org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLBootstrap;

public class CustomSamlBootstrap extends SAMLBootstrap {
    @Override
    public void postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory) throws BeansException {
        super.postProcessBeanFactory(beanFactory);
        BasicSecurityConfiguration config = (BasicSecurityConfiguration) Configuration.getGlobalSecurityConfiguration();
        config.registerSignatureAlgorithmURI("RSA", "http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256");
    }
}
```

Comment: Which spring-security-saml2-core release have you used? I cannot make it work with your suggestion...

Comment: This is using `org.springframework.security.extensions:spring-security-saml2-core:1.0.1.RELEASE` with `org.opensaml:opensaml:2.6.4`.

Answer (score 10):

You can configure digest method for computation of digital signatures by making the following call during Spring SAML initialization:

```
// Use SHA-256 signatures for RSA keys
BasicSecurityConfiguration config = (BasicSecurityConfiguration) Configuration.getGlobalSecurityConfiguration();
config.setSignatureReferenceDigestMethod(SignatureConstants.ALGO_ID_DIGEST_SHA256);
```

For example extend the default `org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLBootstrap` and add the code to the overriden postProcessBeanFactory method after call to super:

```
public void postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory) throws BeansException {
    super.postProcessBeanFactory(beanFactory);
    BasicSecurityConfiguration config = (BasicSecurityConfiguration) Configuration.getGlobalSecurityConfiguration();
    config.setSignatureReferenceDigestMethod(SignatureConstants.ALGO_ID_DIGEST_SHA256);
}
```

This change affects both signatures in generated metadata and signatures in generated SAML messages.

Comment: Hi Vladimir. I'm facing with the same issue, tried the suggested solution but it's not working for me :(
I need to integrates with ADFS, but currently without any success...  
I'm using: spring-security-saml2-core 1.0.4.RELEASE and opensaml 2.6.4

Answer (score 0):

After making the changes in SAMLBootstrap for global security config , I ran into below exception :

> org.apache.xml.security.signature.XMLSignatureException: The requested
>   algorithm SHA256withRSA does not exist. Original Message was:
>   SHA256withRSA MessageDigest not available at
>   org.apache.xml.security.algorithms.MessageDigestAlgorithm.getDigestInstance(Unknown
>   Source) at
>   org.apache.xml.security.algorithms.MessageDigestAlgorithm.getInstance(Unknown
>   Source) at org.apache.xml.security.signature.Reference.(Unknown
>   Source) at
>   org.apache.xml.security.signature.Manifest.addDocument(Unknown Source)
>   at org.apache.xml.security.signature.XMLSignature.addDocument(Unknown
>   Source)

After further investigation found that the Apache XML Security `xmlsec-1.4.3.jar` does not support the underlying `SHA256withRSA` algorithm.

Resolution : Use `xmlsec-2.0.2.jar` from https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.santuario/xmlsec/2.0.2

This new jar resolved the issue .

Comment: Hi guys! I really need help with the same error.
I tried the override solution to set SHA256, I replaced the xmlsec library.. but still, I'm getting the same error from the ADFS.

I'm using:
spring-security-saml2-core 1.0.4.RELEASE
opensaml 2.6.4

Can you please help?