# Issues while integrating ADFS with Spring SAML Extension

Tags: adfs2.0, spring-saml

I am working on integrating Spring SAML Extension within our appliaction and for SSO with one of our client's ADFS2.0 as the IDP we have generated Service provider meta data from our appliaction and imported ADFS meta data into our appliaction.When i select the clients idp and click on start single sign and give the proper clients credentials we are seeing the the SAML response as follows:

Saml Response.

```
<samlp:Response xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol"  Consent="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:consent:unspecified"  
Destination="https://sso.spire2grow.com:8443/<our application>/saml/SSO" ID="_d7fa7cb7-a858-4d4e-aa4c-bf7a5d11e485" 
InResponseTo="a2icei36d347di68gi33534cc13fd1" IssueInstant="2014-09-30T14:17:21.819Z" Version="2.0"><Issuer 
xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion"><Clients ADFS trust services URL></Issuer><samlp:Status><samlp:StatusCode 
Value="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:Responder"></samlp:StatusCode></samlp:Status></samlp:Response>
```

but also i am seeing following exception being thrown as the service provider is not able to validate the message.

Exception message:

```
[351545]2014-09-30 19:47:21,714 DEBUG - SAML message intended destination endpoint matched recipient endpoint
[351545]2014-09-30 19:47:21,714 DEBUG - Authentication attempt using org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLAuthenticationProvider
[351545]2014-09-30 19:47:21,715 DEBUG - Error validating SAML message
org.opensaml.common.SAMLException: Response has invalid status code urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:Responder, status message is null
    at org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl.processAuthenticationResponse(WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(SAMLAuthenticationProvider.java:82)
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:156)
    at org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLProcessingFilter.attemptAuthentication(SAMLProcessingFilter.java:84)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:195)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
```

Could any one please point out if i mising any thing here.

**UPDATE:**

After seeing the answer provided for this question 
I saw the following error from ADFS.

```
Microsoft.IdentityServer.Protocols.Saml.SamlProtocolSignatureAlgorithmMismatchException: MSIS7093: The message is not signed with expected signature algorithm. Message is signed with signature algorithm http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1. Expected signature algorithm http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256. at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.Protocols.Saml.SamlProtocolManager.ValidateSignatureRequirements(SamlMessage samlMessage) at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.Protocols.Saml.SamlProtocolManager.Issue(HttpSamlRequestMessage httpSamlRequestMessage, SecurityTokenElement onBehalfOf, String sessionState, String relayState, String& newSamlSession, String& samlpAuthenticationProvider, Boolean isUrlTranslationNeeded, WrappedHttpListenerContext context, Boolean isKmsiRequested)
```

But after seeing this we did change the Signing algorithm on the relying trust party to rsa-sha256 but still its displaying the same message .

Do we need a genuine certificate for rsa-sha256? Will the self-signed certificate properly work?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The exception from ADFS complains that the SAML message was not signed with RSA-SHA256 which it expects, but with RSA-SHA1.

Make sure to set signing algorithm of the Spring SAML's Relaying Party in ADFS to SHA-1. You can find details in the last bullet point of http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security-saml/1.0.x-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#chapter-idp-guide-adfs-sp

Comment: Any idea why spring-security-saml can't handle ADFS SHA-256 signature?

Comment: By default ADFS is expecting SHA-256 but by default OpenSAML/Spring-Security-SAML is using SHA-1. You have to change one or the other to make them match. The better option is to use SHA-256 so you have to change your implementation like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25982093/setting-the-extendedmetadata-signingalgorithm-field/26004147#26004147

Answer (score 7):

> Value="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:Responder"

See SAML core specification. It says:

> urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:Responder
>   The request could not be performed due to an error on the part of the SAML
>   responder or SAML authority.

i.e. The ADFS server had trouble interpreting or answering the request. The IdP should tell you what the problem is.

Answer (score 5):

Spring Security SAML extension does not support SHA-256 by defualt. You can extend the `org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLBootstrap` class to provide the SHA-256.

Override the `postProcessBeanFactory` method

```
public class Bootstrap extends SAMLBootstrap {

    @Override
    public void postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory) throws BeansException {
        super.postProcessBeanFactory(beanFactory);
        BasicSecurityConfiguration config = (BasicSecurityConfiguration) Configuration
                .getGlobalSecurityConfiguration();
        config.registerSignatureAlgorithmURI("RSA", SignatureConstants.ALGO_ID_SIGNATURE_RSA_SHA256);
        config.setSignatureReferenceDigestMethod(SignatureConstants.ALGO_ID_DIGEST_SHA256);
    }
```

Comment: Like explained [here](https://myshittycode.com/2016/02/23/spring-security-saml-replacing-sha-1-with-sha-256-on-signature-and-digest-algorithms/)