# SAML 2 and ADFS 3.0 IDP - SSO Invalid Status Code First time Login - But succeeds every time after

Tags: spring-saml

We are encountering a

> *Response has invalid status code urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:Responder*

SAMLException trying to run the Spring SAML sample application. The IDP is an ADFS 3.0 Server and the SP uses a self-signed URL. Following is the URL of the SP/App

https://ec2-52-0-198-40.compute-1.amazonaws.com:8443/spring-security-saml2-sample/

The weird thing is this happens after successfully authenticating at the IDP - the first time only. If I try the URL second time, it remembers the successful login and redirects correctly to the app/SP. Every attempt to login after is successful. The Global logout and the Local Logout works too.

But, then If I clear the browser of all cookies and history and try to login again, the "Invalid Status" problem appears the first time around. And all subsequent logins are successful.

@vladimír-schäfer : Any ideas why this problem is happening? Thanks much.

Comment: Hey @Ravikumar Raman, I have the same problem , how did you solve your problem?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49559023/saml-error-for-sso-with-adfs-msis0038-saml-message-has-wrong-signature

Answer (score 0):

One path which is worth trying is to make sure that the HTTPS certificate presented by the site is trusted. I've seen cases when the page used by browsers to confirm invalid certificate breaks data sent during SAML SSO - which could lead to the issue you're experiencing.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response Vladimir. We will install a trusted certificate and let you know.

Comment: Hi Vladimir, we installed a new cert and the new url is https://dev.idiom.digitaslbi.com:8443/spring-security-saml2-sample. We don't get the invalid certificate conformation any more. But the first time **"invalid status code urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:Responder"** still lingers. ADFS(IDP) does not have en error in the logs. Any other path you would like us to try??

Comment: A follow up : The SAML response when it fails(first time log in) has a <Signature> element - But when it succeeds the response  has an <EncryptedAssertion> element, with status 'Success' in it. Wondering what would cause this.

Comment: You should dig more on the ADFS side, perhaps try to enable additional logging. The error has the following meaning "The request could not be performed due to an error on the part of the SAML responder or SAML authority." SAML responder/authority is ADFS in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this when ADFS expects a SHA-256 digital signature but Spring Security still uses SHA-1 as its default.  See [Issues while integrating ADFS with Spring SAML Extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26134655/issues-while-integrating-adfs-with-spring-saml-extension)