# Spring SAML with ADFS: Response doesn't have any valid assertion which would pass subject validation

Tags: java, spring, saml-2.0, adfs, spring-saml

I have to add a SAML implementation on a project. I decided to use Spring SAML. As Service Provider, I generated a metadata file and I sent this file to the IDP.

The IDP did some test. When a user try to connect, I have the following exception : **Response has invalid status code urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:Responder, status message is null**

```
Caused by: org.opensaml.common.SAMLException: Response has invalid status code urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:Responder, status message is null

at org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl.processAuthenticationResponse(WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl.java:113) ~[spring-security-saml2-core-1.0.2.RELEASE.jar:1.0.2.RELEASE]

at org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(SAMLAuthenticationProvider.java:87) ~[spring-security-saml2-core-1.0.2.RELEASE.jar:1.0.2.RELEASE]
... 103 common frames omitted
```

Thanks to All

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26134655/issues-in-integration-adfs-with-spring-saml-extension

Comment: @ymansour can you give me a hint what you did to solve the problem?